# A relation between interior and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A topological space
$X$ is said to be completely regular provided that it is a
Hausdorff space such that, whenever $F$ is a closed set and $x$
is a point in its complement, there exists a function $f\in
C(X)$, the ring of all continuous real function over $X$, such
that $f(x) = 1$ and $f(F) = 0$, in short, $F$ and ${x}$ are
completely separated by a continuous function.

Now let $C_1\subsetneq C_2$ be two closed subset of $X$, a completely regular space. How can we deduce that $\textrm{int}(C_2)\not\subseteq C_1$, where $\textrm{int}(C_2)$ is the
interior set of $C_2$?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

Take $X=\mathbb R, C_1=\{0\}, C_2=\{0,1\}$.

Then $\text{int}(C_2)$ is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is not a discrete space, it contains many counterexamples. Let $p$ be a non-isolated point of $X$. Let $C_1$ be any closed subset of $X$ that does not contain $p$, and let $C_2=C_1\cup\{p\}$. Then $C_1\subsetneqq C_2$, and $\operatorname{int}C_2=\operatorname{int}C_1\subseteq C_1$.